# Extract html using CURL like a iframe?

Tags: php, curl

I have a `html` code that shows the related topics from google trends:

```
<iframe id="trends-widget-1" src='https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/RELATED_TOPICS?req={"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"stack","geo":"BR","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""}&amp;tz=180&amp;eq=geo=BR&q=stack' width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" style="border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 0px 2px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 2px 2px 0px; height: 384px;"></iframe>
```

Now, I want to find a way to save this html (for future use...). For this I try to use `CURL`:

```
$url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/RELATED_TOPICS?req={"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"stack","geo":"BR","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""}&amp;tz=180&amp;eq=geo=BR&q=stack';

        $ch = curl_init();
        $source = $url;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $html;
```

The problem ? `curl` shows a google page with this message:

> 400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

How I can avoid this type of problem and extract the html ?

Comment: The URL parameters in the query string need to be run through [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to avoid the bad request.  Your browser does it automatically but curl does not when you supply the entire URL.

Comment: @drew010 I try this now and I receive a empty webpage....

Comment: Can you update the question or comment with your changes? Copying the URL in your question directly and pasting in the browser also gives the 400.  This works: `$url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/RELATED_TOPICS?req=' . urlencode('{"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"stack","geo":"BR","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""}') . '&tz=180&eq=geo=BR&q=stack';`

Answer (score 0):

The query string part of the source **url** is a mix of html entities and non url-encoded text.

I think this is made on purpose to make more difficult to correctly decode the URL for crawlers.

Anyway, the browser is able to correctly interpret the query string first decoding html entities then identifying each query parameter and its value.

The algorythm used by the browser to do the above decoding is not trivial and there is not a dedicated PHP function that makes the job. If you are interested in the subject I think it would deserve a dedicated question.

For your specific case you can fix the URL this way:

```
// The base URL is ok

$url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/RELATED_TOPICS?';

// The `req` parameter's value must be url-encoded

$url .= 'req=' . urlencode( '{"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"stack","geo":"BR","time":"today 5-y"}],"category":0,"property":""}' );

// The last part of the query string contains html entities, specifically &amp;
// They have to be "translated" into ampersands to let the query make sense
// (I did it manually)
//
// Note also the final part of the query string does not contain special
// characters so I skiped the URL encoding

$url .= '&tz=180&eq=geo=BR&q=stack';
```

You end up with this URL

```
https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/RELATED_TOPICS?req=%7B%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22keyword%22%3A%22stack%22%2C%22geo%22%3A%22BR%22%2C%22time%22%3A%22today+5-y%22%7D%5D%2C%22category%22%3A0%2C%22property%22%3A%22%22%7D&tz=180&eq=geo=BR&q=stack
```

That works fine both pasted in the browser bar and with CURL

---

**Bottom note:**

I'm not sure how much information you'll be able to get from the source of that page once fetched since it makes heavy use of JavaScript and ajax calls to render the content.